# How to locate articles from Expositiones Mathematicae from 1988 and 1992

Tags: reference-request

Unfortunately, my university library seems unable to find the following (I've tried the interlibrary loan tool but this particular journal is somehow outside its scope):

> W. C. Waterhouse, *Analyzing some generalized analytic functions*, Exposition. Math., 10 (1992), 183-192.

and

> I. J. Good, A simple generalization of analytic function theory, Exposition. Math., 6, 4 (1988), 289-311

I believe these are from http://www.journals.elsevier.com/expositiones-mathematicae and I noticed the publisher has made articles from 2000-2010 from *Expositiones Mathematicae* freely available. However, I could not find a way even to purchase a copy of the articles above.

Thanks in advance for any help in finding these papers.

Comment: The problem appears to be that Elsevier has only published this journal since 2004, so perhaps they don't have the rights to older issues.  The issues you're looking for were published by Bibliographisches Institut.  I couldn't find a website for that publisher.  But anyway it's hard to believe that you can't get these via interlibrary loan, since many libraries have full runs of this journal.

Comment: @MichaelZieve hard to believe, yet, true. We don't have Mathscinet among other things. I have been successful in getting other papers through the interlibrary loan tool, but, this particular journal is invisible to the search tool which the library uses.

Comment: [Google says](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Analyzing+some+generalized+analytic+functions%22) that the first paper is [available at ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/238392220_Analyzing_some_generalized_analytic_functions). I decided not to register on RG for several reasons, see [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16870) or [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/24127). (In fact, to me the reputation of that site seems to be bad enough to even consider the possibility that the link does not contain the paper.) Personally, I would try to find other ways.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Research Gate is indeed not a reliable source, their software indicates that W.C. Waterhouse is not as of yet on RG. Sadly, Waterhouse passed on June 26 of this year (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_C._Waterhouse, there is a linked obituary).

Comment: When Alfred Foster passed away, I offered to distribute some of his preprints he had left of his published articles for the cost of postage.  If you contact one of Waterhouse's colleagues or institutions, you might find someone who is willing to do something similar.  There might even be a collection of articles containing the paper of Good's  you want that people  handling the estate might let you have. Gerhard "It Is OK To Ask" Paseman, 2016.07.02.

Comment: @MichaelZieve following your suspicion, I tried the interlibrary loan system again. The journal does not appear in the search engine for the loan system, but, I went ahead and filled out the form with the information. Guess I'll find out if it works in a few days...

Answer (score 3):

Great news, the inter-library loan system worked once I ignored the search engine and just tried to make the request directly. Thanks to @Michael Zieve for encouraging me to try the library again.